# Keras Neural Net Loss Function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, loss-function

I've encountered a problem while writing Siamese net. Definition of the net takes as an input 2 vectors which represents 2 pieces of text. The vectors length is padded and different with respect to batches (in batch 1: vectors length = 32, in batch 2: vectors length = 64 and so on).

```
# model definition
def create_model(vocab_size=512, d_model=128):
    def normalize(x):
        norm = tf.norm(x, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
        return tf.divide(x, norm)

    component = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, d_model),
        tf.keras.layers.LSTM(d_model),
        tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.reduce_mean(x, axis=1)),
        tf.keras.layers.Lambda(normalize),
    ])
    # due to the variability in text, input shape differs with respect to batch 
    inputs = [tf.keras.Input(shape=(None,)) for _ in range(2)]
    outputs = tf.tuple([component(ins) for ins in inputs])

    return tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

# loss function
class MyLoss(tf.keras.losses.Loss):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(name='TripletLoss')

    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        # >>> HERE IS THE PROBLEM, y_pred has different shape then I'd expect,
        # its shape is (batch_size,) instead of (2, batch_size)
        l, r = y_pred 
        # compute and return loss 
        return loss
```

When calling `Model#fit(loss=MyLoss(), ...)` the parameter passed to the `MyLoss#call` is a projection of the first coordinate of the model prediction, i.e. `model.predict(z)` returns `[x, y]` where `x, y` are vectors with length equal to the batch size. I'd expected that `y_pred` passed as a parameter to Loss#call would have had that exact value, that is `[x,y]`, but it equals to the first vector of the given list, that is `x`. Furthermore I've looked up at the call stack and I've spotted that before `y_pred` is passed to the `MyLoss#call` it has expected value (`[x,y]`) which changes to the `x` in the keras' `Loss.__call__` body.

I tried to reshape input, but other problems arised.

Comment: The problem you're experiencing is that Tensorflow executes the loss function twice---once for each output tensor. In this case, if I understand correctly, you want to pass both tensors simultaneously to the loss function. Can you try stacking the two output tensors instead of producing a tuple? ``outputs = tf.stack([component(ins) for ins in inputs], axis=0)``